# protected inherientence with virtual function

Tags: c++

I write a virtual function with protected inherientence

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class D{
private:
    int a;
protected:
    int b;
public:
    D(){a=b=c=0;}
    virtual void f(){
    a=2;
    cout <<"D::f"<<a<<endl;
    }
    void g(){cout<<"D::g"<<a<<endl;}
    int c;
};
class E:protected D{
    private:
        int a,b,c;
    public:
        E(){a=b=c;}
        void f(){
            a=3;
            cout<<"E::f"<<a<<endl;
        }
        void g(){cout<<"E::g"<<a<<endl;}
};
int main(){
    D *d = new E;
    d->f();
    d->g();
    return 0;
}
```

but if I use it, it turn out inaccessible base.

If I change it to public inherience , it can run.

I wonder that why I cannot use  D *d = new E; with private and protected inherience?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`private` or `protected` base means the base is *inaccessible* to the world. So when you write an expression which requires conversion from the derived to the *inaccessible* base, that is forbidden due to accessibility rules *because* the conversion needs to take place at the call-site which is a part of the world.

In object-oriented terminology, `private` or `protected` base  doesn't define **is-a** relationship. It is actually an *implemented-in-terms-of* relationship, which is composition in simpler term.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand how it violate the accessiblity rule?
I think that I just make a base class pointer to the derived class only.

Comment: @Liang-YuPan: The base, being protected, cannot be accessed from outside. It is NOT a base in object-oriented sense when you view it from outside. Try to understand the `protected` thing.

Answer (score 1):

because non-public inheritance does not define a "is-a" relationship, compiler generally will not allow implicit up-cast

The following would have worked, but it's a bad idea/design

```
D*d = (D*)(new E);
```